# In Bash Script Second Argument to Function is not Processed as Expected

Tags: linux, bash, git

Trying to combine git - add/commit/push in one fuction.

gitacp testfile/testfile.py "testing" works okay.

gitacp testfile/testfile.py "testing this" results in this error.
error: pathspec 'this' did not match any file(s) known to git.

From some reason the set of strings in the second argument is not
getting processed correctly.

```
# Git add, commit and push
function gitacp {
    args=("$@")
    filepathname=${args[0]}
    comment=${args[1]}
    branchname=$(git status 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f3)
    git add ${filepathname}
    git commit -m ${comment}
    echo ${branchname}
    echo ${branchnmrmspc}
    echo ${comment}
    echo ${filepathname}
    git push --set-upstream origin ${branchname}
}
```

```
gitacp testfile/testfile.py "testing this" results in this error.
error: pathspec 'this' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: The problem is missing quotes.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to identify such problems, and many other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the argument

```
git commit -m "${comment}"
```